# ejabberd 18.09 and MySQL version not supported

Tags: mysql, ejabberd

I have installed ejabberd version 18.09, I configured ejabberd Mysql module according to [Using ejabberd with MySQL](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/databases/mysql/). ejabberd starts correctly but i receive this errors on logs:

> 2018-11-20 16:27:08.893 [error] <0.438.0>@ejabberd_sql:log:963 MySQL
>   version not supported: MySQL Erlang module might not work correctly.
>
> 2018-11-20 16:27:08.893 [debug] <0.449.0>@ejabberd_sql:log:961
>   p1_mysql_conn: greeting version "8.0.13" (protocol 10) salt ")q#'u:AM"
>   caps 65535 serverchar <<255,2,0,255,195,21,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0>> salt2
>   [126,23,122,96,120,108,41,115,123,66,37,45]

I have to say Mysql version is 8.0.13.0 CE.

do I have downgrade Mysql or update ejabberd Mysql module?

Comment: the [docs](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/databases/mysql/) claim "you need MySQL 5.6 or greater" so it should be ok. But you could ask the maintainers, to be certain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the p1_mysql library, support for MySQL 8 was added recently, and not yet included in any release. You can try to update that library manually, or use ejabberd from git until next ejabberd release.

https://github.com/processone/p1_mysql/commit/8fc8c08657bebc761c83a6b07dc25824b76a2ecf
https://github.com/processone/p1_mysql/commit/fccad9b5e15377d47d51bbfe05ca9646f519f3ef